# R, create new column that consists of 1st column or if condition is met, a value from the 2nd/3rd column

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

```
           a       b      c    d
1     boiler   maker   <NA> <NA> 
2      clerk assistant <NA> <NA> 
3     senior machine setter <NA> 
4   operated    <NA>   <NA> <NA> 
5 consultant    legal  <NA> <NA>
```

How do I create a new column that takes the value in column 'a' unless any of the other columns contain either `legal` or `assistant` in which case it takes that value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a base-R solution. We use `apply` and `any` to test every column at once.

```
df$col <- as.character(df$a)
df$col[apply(df == "Legal",1,any)] <- "Legal"
df$col[apply(df == "assistant",1,any)] <- "assistant"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
library("dplyr")

df %>%
    mutate(new=ifelse(b=="Legal" | c=="Legal" | d=="Legal", "Legal",
                      ifelse(b=="assistant" | c=="assistant" | d=="assistant", "assistant",
                             as.character(a))))
```

`as.character` is need if values where `factors`. If not, it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

A base R alternative of @scoa's answer:

```
indx <- apply(mydf == "Legal",1,any) + apply(mydf == "assistant",1,any)*2 + 1L
mydf$col <- c("a","Legal","Assistent")[indx]
```

or in one go:

```
mydf$col <- c("a","Legal","Assistent")[apply(mydf == "Legal",1,any) + apply(mydf == "assistant",1,any)*2 + 1L]
```

which gives:

```
> mydf
           a         b      c    d       col
1     boiler     maker   <NA> <NA>         a
2      clerk assistant   <NA> <NA> Assistent
3     senior   machine setter <NA>         a
4   operated      <NA>   <NA> <NA>         a
5 consultant     Legal   <NA> <NA>     Legal
```